# Is OpenSSL latest version secure

Tags: php, security, openssl

I am developing a PHP web app using apache as a web server. I would like to know if OpenSSL in its latest version is secure, or is it vulnerable beacause of heartbleed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last OpenSSL vulnerability was found in the middle of this month ([CVE-2014-3513](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2014-3513)).

Hearbleed is fixed on [April 7th](https://www.httpcs.com/news/heartbleed-openssl-explanation-and-exploit). Now, for your case, it depends on the version of OpenSSL you are running. Check the full list on [here](https://www.openssl.org/source/).

You can find the list of OpenSSL vulnerabilities since HeartBleed bug on [here](https://www.openssl.org/news/vulnerabilities.html).

Comment: The CVE was created May 2014, so it was discovered before then.